# Variable cannot be mutable in a "for" loop

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to  calculate the optimum ADX limit with a for loop within my strategy script but I ran into the error: variable cannot be mutable for my "limit ADX" variable. Can anyone Help me on this?

I also try to have the while loop for the ADX length to but the ADX calculation does not allow it since the lengths need to be simple int :( So, the while loop can be disregarded.

```
//@version=5
import TradingView/ta/6
import TradingView/Strategy/3

SystemName = 'Risk Management Strategy'
// These values are used both in the strategy() header and in the script's relevant inputs as default values so they match.
// Unless these values match in the script's Inputs and the TV backtesting Properties, results between them cannot be compared.
InitCapital = 100000
InitPosition = 10.0
InitCommission = 0.075
InitPyramidMax = 1
CalcOnorderFills = true

strategy(title=SystemName, shorttitle=SystemName, overlay=true, pyramiding=InitPyramidMax, initial_capital=InitCapital, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=InitPosition, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=InitCommission, calc_on_order_fills=CalcOnorderFills, calc_on_every_tick = true, precision=6, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500, max_bars_back = 5000)

//  You capture the Source of your indicator here
ext_source_ = input(close, title='Data source')
ext_source_2 = input(close, title='Exit source')
// variables initialisation
ext_source = nz(ext_source_)
ext_source2 = nz(ext_source_2)
account = input.float(1000, "Account",inline="1")
margin = input.int(1,"Margin")
tr_perc = input.int(10,"Trailing with Exit")/100

// 1 is bull signal
bull = ext_source == 1

// 2 exit custom close long
exit_bull = ext_source == 2

// Sizing
size = 10

//11-ADX Filter input
use_adx = input.bool(false,title="",display = display.none)
//ADX for filter
dirmov(int len) =>
    up = ta.change(high)
    down = -ta.change(low)
    plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
    minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
    truerange = ta.rma(ta.tr, len)
    plus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(plusDM, len) / truerange)
    minus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(minusDM, len) / truerange)
    [plus, minus]
adx(int len) =>
    [plus, minus] = dirmov(len)
    sum = plus + minus
    adx = 100 * ta.rma(math.abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), len)

//Variable for best restults
profitability = 0.00
profit_ratio = 0.00
profitability0 = 0.00
profit_ratio0 = 0.00

int adx_len=5
int adx_len0=0
int lim_adx0=0
// Entry Price
entry_price = ta.valuewhen(bull, source=close, occurrence=0)

//Exit
SL0 = 0
SL = strategy.openprofit/(strategy.position_avg_price)*margin > tr_perc ? strategy.position_size > 0 ? math.round(math.max(ext_source2,SL0),3) : strategy.position_size < 0 ? math.round(math.min(ext_source2,SL0),3) : math.round(ext_source2,3) : SL0
        
//Entry
while adx_len < 30
    sig = adx(adx_len)
    
    for varip lim_adx = 10 to 30
        if bull  and strategy.position_size == 0  and (use_adx ? sig > lim_adx : true) 
            strategy.order("Long N = 0",direction = strategy.long,qty=size,stop = entry_price)

        SL := SL[1] > SL ? SL[1] : SL
        if strategy.position_size > 0 and (low < SL or exit_bull)
            strategy.cancel_all()
            strategy.exit("Long Exit SL",qty = strategy.position_size, stop = SL)
            if strategy.position_size != 0
                strategy.close_all("Closed All")

        profitability:= math.round(strategy.wintrades/strategy.closedtrades,4)*100
        profit_ratio := 1 + math.round(strategy.netprofit/strategy.grossloss,2)
        //best profitability
        if profitability0 < profitability
            profitability0 := profitability
            profit_ratio0 := profit_ratio
            adx_len0 := adx_len
            lim_adx0 := lim_adx

        lim_adx += 1
    adx_len += 1
```

I tried setting the variable type to simple int but did not work

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example. This code does not compile and unnecessarily long.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for comment. I reduced the lines to remove things not related to the problem. Nevertheless, note that I am using a private library for SL0, and therefore it won't compile if you just copy this strategy.

Comment: why do you have ` lim_adx := lim_adx + 1` ? Shouldn't the increments be done by  `for lim_adx = 10 to 30` ?

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, ir does not seem to work that way :( Also, the manual's examples have the  add 1 at the end of the loop.

I have tested one by one for TSLA and in my current setting I know that lim_adx should be 23. My code always gives me either 10 or 30, never a value in between the two limits.

Comment: The code still does not compile.

Comment: @vitruvius what error do you get?
maybe you need to add something like:
`strategy(title=SystemName, shorttitle=SystemName, overlay=true, pyramiding=InitPyramidMax, initial_capital=InitCapital, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=InitPosition, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=InitCommission, calc_on_order_fills=CalcOnorderFills, calc_on_every_tick = true, precision=6, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500, max_bars_back = 5000)`

Comment: Copy and paste the code you shared and you will see the errors I get.

Comment: Updated to a simplified version that compiles

Comment: Removing ``lim_adx := +1`` throws no error. However, plotting adx_len0 and lim_adx0 shows that they are the initial values, which is the wrong result :(

Answer (score 0):

You define your `for` loop as follows:

```
for varip lim_adx = 10 to 30
```

And then you try to modify the counter `lim_adx` later in the body of the loop which is not allowed and also does not make any sense.

Remove `lim_adx += 1`  from your code and it will compile.

However, this code is unfortunately very poorly written and it will not do what you are aiming for.